# Prove that $f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is consistently continuous

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Prove that $f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$
>   is consistently continuous

Let $\delta > 0$, let $\varepsilon > 0$, let $|x-x_{0}|< \delta$

$\Rightarrow$

$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_{0}}| > |\sqrt{x-x_{0}}| < \sqrt{\delta} = \varepsilon$$

$$\delta = \varepsilon^{2}$$

---

Is it correct?

Comment: Uniformly continuous?

Comment: you should never have these switching >, < in these types of proofs.

Comment: What does the term "consistently" mean in the context herein?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{|x-x_0|}$?

Comment: Assuming that "consistent" means "uniform", the proof is neither correct nor incorrect, it doesn't look as a mathematical text at all. A proof should start with assumptions, follow small logical steps, and end up with the conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things are wrong with this "proof," the most critical of which is the end statement $\delta = \epsilon^2$.  If you start with just $\delta > 0$ and $\epsilon >0$ and come to the conclusion that  $\delta = \epsilon^2$ you can be sure you did something wrong.

However, I see what you are doing:  You are trying to find how small $\delta$ will have to be for any given $\epsilon$.  Say you start with "Let $\delta = \frac14\epsilon^2$" and then proceed to say $$
| f(x) - f(x_0) | = |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}| \leq \sqrt{|x-x_0|} = \sqrt{\delta} = \frac12 \epsilon < \epsilon
$$
Well now you have something resembling a proof (though you should mention that this $\delta$ does not depend on $x_0$) but there is still a big step missing:

Why is $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}| \leq \sqrt{|x-x_0|}$ ????

That is the meaty part of the problem.  The statement is true, but you need to prove it. (Hint: consider the case of $x>x_0$ and square both sides.  Then consider other cases.)